# ios technology that allow create browser such as Skyfire/Puffin

Tags: iphone, ios, browser, x11

I saw browsers on iOS (such as Skyfire, Puffin, and others) that 
They process web content on server and then transfer it to iDevice.
They can show Flash content and allow interaction with it.
I want to do such thing in my app
Are there any technologies that I can use for that?
I think I can  run firefox on my server and use X11 Forwarding to communicate with it. 
Are there x and ssh clients for iOS the I can embed in my app?

May be some other alternatives?

Im looking for some technology (may be proprietary and paid) that can be used to process web pages remotely and then sent them in some form to ios device, with possibility for interaction with page.

**Edit**
Skyfire, Photon, iSwifter and others run desktop browsers in cloud.
Are there any cloud hostings that provide such service (running Firefox)?
Or creators of this mobile browsers do it by themselves? (creating and configuring servers)

Comment: Do you really think X11-forwarding is your best solution?

Comment: I'm looking for a suitable solution.

Comment: Well I don't have a solution for you, other than attempting to reuse some of the code provided in these third party browsers (kind of like `UIWebView` provides access to WebKit).  X11 forwarding is almost certainly the worst solution you could choose.

Comment: I know very small about X11 forwarding. Why it si worst solution?

Comment: Because it will be slow and you have a lot of work getting the X11 libraries compiled for iOS, however that opinion is based on *intuition* more than *experience*.

Comment: @Petr, Hello, Did you at the end come up with any idea? Cause I also want to develop same thing what you do. If you have any suggestion, please share. A lot of thanks in advance.

Comment: no, for now we are working on other (more important) project. we didnt find any solutions for this yet.